# How to access memory leaks tool while testing on iPad device?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

So I'm using the memory leaks debugging tool by selecting "Profile" under the "Run" submenu.

I can run and record fine on the iOS simulator, but if I select my iPad device, the record button is greyed out/unselectable. I tried messing with my Profile scheme, changing it to Debug and Instrument: Leaks but its still greyed out. The app doesn't execute in my iPad either, like it normally would on Run.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably.. you are missing the developer profile.. 
1. change the build settings
2. Select the developer profile in build settings
3. Build the application
4. Try to profile this with instruments.